# Tkinter OptionMenu limit?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, styles

I have some `OptionMenu`s in my GUI that store long strings.
[image]

Is there a way how I could limit the number of shown digits/letters of the selected value?

I want to safe some open space in my GUI so I need to find a way to limit those `OptionMenu`s

I cant find any option for `OptionMenu`s in their docs.

Comment: If the length of your select longer than the specific length, replace redundant letters to `"..."`.Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes kinda. I would like to have a specific width for the OptionMenu (would do this with `width`) and if the select it longer than the width it should be cut off  so the text does not overlap other widgets.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Bind `StringVar` and function for your `tk.OptionMenu`.The function will receive the value you select in the dropdown menu.(You also need to use monospace font,)So I think you could get the selected value by the passed value.And use `StringVar` to set the display value.Like:

```
import tkinter as tk

width = 10

def strip_str(val):
    selected_value = var.get()
    var.set(selected_value[:width] + ("" if len(selected_value) <= width else "..."))
    print(val)


r = tk.Tk()
r.option_add("*font", ("Consolas", 10))
value_list = ["arc (arc, chord, or pieslice)","bitmap (built-in or read from XBM file)","image (a BitmapImage or PhotoImage instance)","line","oval (a circle or an ellipse)","polygon","rectangle","text","window"]
var = tk.StringVar()
menu = tk.OptionMenu(r, var, *value_list, command=strip_str)
menu.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

---

PS: The value in the OptionsMenu has been changed, though, the variable `val` is the value you selected before.Just handling `val` in the function is okay.

Comment: But the default font of all the widgets in the window is `Consolas`.

Comment: @KevinMayo To prevent that, you could use a frame which only contains this `OptionsMenu`, then use `frame.option_add()`.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for an answer how to do it with OptionMenu:

add: `width=10, anchor='w')`  to the config.

This will do it with `OptionMenu`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ttk Combobox instead of the option menu.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['Hello World!', 'Goodbye World!'])
cmb.grid()
```

This will be displayed like so.

[image: Original]

```
cmb.configure(width=10)  # Can also set this when you create the combobox
```

Now it is cut off.

[image: After changing the width]

Comment: Combobox would be great, but I then have the problem , tht I dont know how to make them update the values and also the selected valuse (after I launched the GUI).

Comment: I'm not following you here. You just want the selected value of the combobox? You also want to update the values in the combobox?

Comment: its kinda complex. When I start the GUi the Optionmenues are empty. I scrape data from a URL and trace the StringVars. With a callback function I then update my optionmenus.
But   Ihave no clue about ttk and combobox. So I dont know how I handle that.

Comment: The main difference between ttk and tk are how its presented. For the combobox you could do something like: currentValues = list(cmb.cget("values")). This will get what's currently in the combobox. Then, you can update it like so. cmb.configure(values=currentValues + ["New Entry"]) and it will update. For reference: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Combobox.html